# React: Why the onChange event does not trigger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a date picker.

It works fine. Unfortunately, I have added the `onChange` handler to the input box, however, it does not be triggered.

I have referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288814/react-setting-input-value-with-javascript-does-not-trigger-onchange) it told me that using the state variable can solve the problem.

However, I am using the `useReducer` instead of 'useState', is it why the `onChange` event does not be triggered?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5jdjbb?file=src%2FdatePicker%2FDatePicker.js) is my code.

Comment: Could it possible to move the reducer function out of the default function?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I use `useEffect` to monitor the change of `context.displayDate` to solve the problem.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(contextValue.displayDate);      
}, [contextValue.displayDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it seems if you update `onChange` to `onBlur` it works fine.

The documentation seems to suggest that onChange is only triggered for user changes to the value of the input field.

Example

```
 <input
   onBlur={e => handleChange(e)}
   onClick={showCalendar}
   type="text"
   value={contextValue.displayDate}
   readOnly
 />
```

Comment: However, it does not reflect the latest value.

Comment: Could that just be the console.log being placed in the wrong place?

I have updated the code to what is the correct approach to onBlur, I had just quickly updated what you already had. Now if you log e.target.value in the handleChange function it should give you the correct value.

Comment: I have changed the code as your described, it still shows the previous value.

Comment: Okay I have looked at your code.. You are manually controlling the value field so it is showing the previous value because you have updated the `context.displayDate`.

This means the value does not equal what the user selects but rather the current value which you have manually forced.

My advice is to add a callBack to the calendar on click and get the value that way since you have build something very custom

Comment: There are plenty of good date pickers online which I would recommend to reduce the complexity even just using the default HTML date picker would solve your issues

Comment: Finally, I use `useEffect` to monitor the change of  `context.displayDate`  to solve the problem.

Comment: If this solved your issue please mark it as answered so that other people can use it :)